# PostgreSQL: multiple exists return incorrect result

Tags: postgresql, exists

Please, see the following [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/m5kG4ZBe) for a complete example. Why does `Query 2` return different results than `Query 1`? I think `Query 2` have correlated subqueries, so they should be executed once per row, but it works like subqueries is joined with `OR` not `AND`.

```
-- Query 1

SELECT id
FROM parent p
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM child
    WHERE child.parent_id = p.id AND child.field_1 = 1 AND child.field_2 = 1
)

-- Query 2

SELECT id
FROM parent p
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM child
    WHERE child.parent_id = p.id AND child.field_1 = 1
) AND EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM child
    WHERE child.parent_id = p.id AND child.field_2 = 1
)
```

Actual results for `Query 1`:

```
id
--
2
3
4
```

Actual results for `Query 2`:

```
id
--
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get different results because you ran different queries.

In the first one, there needs to be a single child row which matches all 3 conditions.

In the second one, there needs to be a child row for each set of conditions, but it doesn't have to be the same child row both times.